# How do I write my Aspect classes and my problem solves?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postsharp, log4postsharp

I have 2 errors because of my little knowledge of PostSharp (last version). My project's three aspect classes, but I only get 2 errors. When the getall method runs in my mvc project, I want log information to be generated in my database and C:/Log/Log.txt. But no logs are created. Here is what I want from you. No matter how I write the code block, my problem solves? I have some validation and Transaction processes, but I don't think it has anything to do with the error I'm getting, so there's no need for details. Firstly, I've gotten the following warning.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1CY7.png)

To solve this, I followed the procedure below. LogAspect and FluentValidationAspect classes have been giving error.

```
[LogAspect(AspectPriority = 1), FluentValidationAspect(AspectPriority = 2), TransactionScopeAspect(AspectPriority = 3)]
```

And again, I got the following error. (CS 7036)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wd6li.png)

I want to do some operations in my BookManager class. (Log, Validation, Transaction). Here are the codes;

```
 [LogAspect(AspectPriority = 1), FluentValidationAspect(AspectPriority = 2), TransactionScopeAspect(AspectPriority = 3)]
public class BookManager : IBookService
{

    private  IBookDal _bookDal;
    private  IPersonDal _personDal;
    
    /* private readonly IQueryableRepository<Book> _queryable; */
    public BookManager(IBookDal bookDal, IPersonDal personDal/*IQueryableRepository<Book> queryable */)
    {
        _personDal = personDal;
        /*_queryable = queryable; */
        _bookDal = bookDal;
    }
   [FluentValidationAspect(typeof(BookValidator))]
    
    public Book Add(Book book)
    {
        return _bookDal.Add(book);
    }

    public void Delete(Book book)
    {
        _bookDal.Delete(book);
    }
    [LogAspect(typeof(DatabaseLogger))]
    public List<Book> GetAll()
    {
        return _bookDal.GetList();
    }
    [TransactionScopeAspect]
    public void TransactionalOperation(Person person, Book book)
    {
        _personDal.Delete(person);
        // Business Codes
        _bookDal.Add(book);
    }

    public Book GetById(int bookId)
    {
        return _bookDal.Get(p=>p.BookId==bookId);
    }
   [FluentValidationAspect(typeof(BookValidator))]
    public Book Update(Book book)
    {
        return _bookDal.Update(book);
    }
}
[Serializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(MulticastTargets.Method, TargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.Instance)]

public class LogAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    
    private  Type _loggerType;
    [NonSerialized]
    private LoggerService _loggerService;
    public LogAspect(Type loggerType)
    {
        _loggerType = loggerType;
    }

    public override void RuntimeInitialize(MethodBase method)
    {

        if (_loggerType.BaseType != typeof(LoggerService))
        {
            throw new Exception("Wrong logger type.");
        }
        
        _loggerService = (LoggerService)Activator.CreateInstance(_loggerType);
        base.RuntimeInitialize(method);
    }
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        if (!_loggerService.IsInfoEnabled)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            var logParameters = args.Method.GetParameters().Select((t, i) => new LogParameter
            {
                Name = t.Name,
                Type = t.ParameterType.Name,
                Value = args.Arguments.GetArgument(i)
            }).ToList();
            var logDetail = new LogDetail
            {
                FullName = args.Method.DeclaringType == null ? null : args.Method.DeclaringType.Name,
                MethodName = args.Method.Name,
                Parameters = logParameters
            };
            _loggerService.Info(logDetail);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            
        }
        
    }
}
 [Serializable]
public class FluentValidationAspect : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
    Type _validatorType;
    public FluentValidationAspect(Type validatorType)
    {
        _validatorType = validatorType;
    }
    public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
    {
        var validator = (IValidator)Activator.CreateInstance(_validatorType);
        var entityType = _validatorType.BaseType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var entities = args.Arguments.Where(t => t.GetType() == entityType);
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            ValidatorTool.FluentValidate(validator, entity);
        }
    }
}
```

> I want to tell you something that you have to consider. Also, I did assembly level logging. This is the code.

```
[assembly: LogAspect(typeof(JsonFileLogger), AttributeTargetTypes = "ELibrary.Library.Business.Managers.BookManager*")]
```

Finally I want to add, can you explain the solution of this error by rewriting the wrong block?

Answer (score 0):

Ordering aspects is documented [here](https://doc.postsharp.net/aspect-dependencies). You are getting the warning because PostSharp does not have information on the ordering of some transformations. In your case I'd add the following attribute on `LogAspect`:

`[AspectTypeDependency(AspectDependencyAction.Order, AspectDependencyPosition.Before, typeof(FluentValidationAspect))]`

And then on `FluentValidationAspect`:

`[AspectTypeDependency(AspectDependencyAction.Order, AspectDependencyPosition.Before, typeof(TransactionScopeAspect))]`

This should totally order those three aspects and you should get rid of warnings.

Afterwards, you were getting C# errors because your aspect constructors simply have a parameter that you did not specify. AspectPriority needs to be specified on individual attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but I've noticed something. I've removed Aspects on BookManager.cs's operations. And then on AssemblyLine, while this code was written, it didn't work either. I wonder if there is a problem with my log codes? Can you look at github repo? [github link](https://github.com/ogulcanakca/ELibrary/tree/master)